# Can you add a decorator to parent methods and variables from a child class?

Tags: java

Is it possible to add a @ decorator to a parent class's field or method without hiding it (without using super)?

> Code below produces:
> ***colA = null**, colA = Hello World, ttl = 360*
> notice the toString has null for the parent

```
abstract class TableA {

    protected String colA;
    
    public String toString() {
        return "colA = " + this.colA;
    }
}

class TableAImpl extends TableA {
    
    //@Computed("ttl(value)")
    int myTtl;
    
    //*** NOTICE THIS  ***
    //@PartitionKey
    protected String colA;
    
    public TableAImpl(int ttl, String colA) {
        this.myTtl = ttl;
        this.colA = colA;
    }
    
    //*** NOTICE THIS  ***
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + ", colA = " + this.colA + ", ttl = " + this.myTtl;
    }
}

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        TableAImpl a = new TableAImpl(360, "Hello World");
        System.out.println(a.toString());
     }
}
```

***Context:***
I need to support multiple database types so I have a generic Entity class which are overloaded by DB specific Implementation classes. These DB specific classes overload/add the specific logic to interface with that DB, which should be invisible to the caller.

For one of the DBs used, the java driver's logic is primarily done by adding @Decorators to the Entity Class's methods and attributes which it uses to generate helper code.

When I try the below code to add decorators to them, the child class's variables hide the parent's

Comment: I'm guessing probably not; as decorators are at compile time and the native decorator parser probably wasn't built to be "smart" enough for this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've never set parent's `colA` attribute.

```java
public TableAImpl(int ttl, String colA) {
    this.myTtl = ttl;
    this.colA = colA;
    super.colA = colA;
}
```

To protect parent's `colA` you should set it private with `private` and a `getter` like so :

```java
abstract class TableA {

    private String colA;

    public TableA() {}
    public TableA(String colA) {
        this.colA = colA;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "colA = " + this.colA;
    }

    protected String getColA() {
        return colA;
    }
}

class TableAImpl extends TableA {

    //@Computed("ttl(value)")
    int myTtl;

    public TableAImpl(int ttl, String colA) {
        super(colA);
        this.myTtl = ttl;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + ", colA = " + this.getColA() + ", ttl = " + this.myTtl;
    }

    //*** NOTICE THIS  ***
    //@PartitionKey
    @Override
    public String getColA() {
        return super.getColA();
    }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String []args){
        TableAImpl a = new TableAImpl(360, "Hello World");
        System.out.println(a.toString());
        // colA = Hello World, colA = Hello World, ttl = 360
    }
}
```

Comment: The goal is to only have 1 colA variable, but add the decorator @PartitionKey in the child class. With your change the code still ends up with 2 distinct variables (super's & this's). This means the child code would have to use super.colA everywhere, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: public TableAImpl(int ttl, String colA) {
        this.myTtl = ttl;
        //this.colA = colA;
        super.colA = colA;
    }
Produces: 
colA = Hello World, **colA = null,** ttl = 360

Comment: I updated my post so you have a correct implementation.
You may set your annotation on our getter and override your parent's access

Comment: Note that @Override annotation is optionnal. Override is based on scope and public is wider than protected (inherited)

Comment: Thanks! If this works, this is exactly what I was hoping for. I'm not sure if the DB library works with the decorator on the getter instead of the variable itself though. If it does, this will be the accepted answer.

Comment: You said : `@Decorators to the Entity Class's methods and attributes which it uses to generate helper code` :D

Comment: Ideally I would like a method of adding decorators to both, methods *and* attributes. The library I'm using supports the decorator on the getter as well as the attribute itself, so this solution solves my current issue though, so I've accepted it as the approved solution.

Comment: This implementation is a standard of encapsulation, frameworks and libs should support decorator on getters as it's required (just like what your problem exposed) :)